# How to create linked (href) labels in a d3 circle packing chart?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, label, circle-pack

I am working with this example: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/pack-hierarchy.html

[image]

I am pretty new to d3 and having a really hard time linking the labels (at the most zoomed in level) to external sites.

Comment: You might want to check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21273702/3128209); it's based on a different layout, but the basics are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it based on the same example:

```
  vis.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "parent" : "child"; })
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
  .on("click", function(d) {

    if(typeof d.children === 'undefined' && d  != node){
      vis.selectAll("text")
         .style("pointer-events","all")
         .style("fill","#0000EE")
         .style("font-size","32px")
         .style("cursor","pointer")
         .style("text-decoration","underline")
    }     
    else
    {
      vis.selectAll("text")
         .style("pointer-events","none")
         .style("fill","black")
         .style("font-size","14px")
         .style("text-decoration","none")

    }

    return zoom(node == d ? root : d); 

    });
```

The trick is modifying the css to activate pointer-events when zoomed to the farthest level, then throwing in an on-click function with the select text element...

```
vis.selectAll("text")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("svg:text")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "parent" : "child"; })
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("opacity", function(d) { return d.r > 20 ? 1 : 0; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .on("click",function(d){
    window.location = d.url});
```

Here is an example of the json file with links

```
 "name": "NIFA",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "Developers","url":"http://nifa.org/programs/index.html",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Prairie Gold Homes", "size": 3179,"url":"http://nifa.org/programs/index.html?topic=desc&ovr_ov=-over&prog_name_sent=Prairie+Gold+Homes"},
    {"name": "NebHi-RED", "size": 4060,"url":"http://nifa.org/programs/index.html?topic=desc&ps=choose&prog_name_sent=NebHi-RED"},
    {"name": "CROWN", "size": 4138,"url":"http://nifa.org/programs/index.html?topic=desc&ps=choose&prog_name_sent=CROWN"},
    {"name": "Bingo Bonds", "size": 1690,"url":"http://nifa.org/programs/index.html?topic=desc&ovr_ov=-over&prog_name_sent=BINGO+Bonds"},
    {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830,"url":"http://nifa.org/programs/index.html?topic=desc&ps=choose&prog_name_sent=Infrastructure+Loan+Guarantee"}
   ]
  },
```

hope that helps!